# Importing non duplicate records from a XML file to a SQL server with LINQ

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, linq, import

I have a SQL server database with the following structure:

```
[Order]
OrderId
CustomerId
(...)

[OrderDetail]
OrderDetailId
OrderId
ProductId
Quantity 
(....)
```

I want to import an xml file like this that can contain records already inserted in the database:

```
<import>
    <orders>
        <order Id="1" />
        <order Id="2" />
        <order Id="3" />
    </order>
    <orderDetails>
        <orderDetail id="1" orderId="1" product="123" quantity="1" />
        <orderDetail id="2" orderId="1" product="456" quantity="5" />
    </orderDetails>
</import>
```

What is the most optimal way to read the xml file with LINQ2XML and check the database and insert only the non duplicate (new) rows to the database using LINQ2SQL?

Comment: What do you have so far? Have you tried to write the linq statement for it? The implementation should be something like: Get all products from DB, get all products from xml, insert those in xml that doesn't exists in DB.

Comment: Is there a reason for needing to use Linq? You would be better off using SSIS to import the data.

Comment: I can't use SSIS because I'm running the application in a shared hosting, anyway the xml file is very simple using SSIS would be overkill

Answer (score 0):

Since both of these tables have ID columns, you could just surround the insertion method with a try/catch and trap any PK exceptions. Sounds fairly efficient to me.